# Rhino-mocks Unit Testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I am writing Unit Test for this Method. I am using Rhino Mocks. How can I Write test case as in msdn document?

```
mockSet.Verify(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Blog>()), Times.Once()); // Looking for Equivalent in Rhino Mocks

public class Person
{
     public string FirstName {get;set;}
     public string LastName {get;set;}
}

public Person Create(Person entity)
{
    GetDbSet().Add(entity);
    SaveChanges();  
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
_context = mocks.DynamicMock<ApplicationDbContext>();
```